# What is Inbound/Outbound data transfer?

Tags: amazon-s3, hosting, data-transfer

Amazon allows free inbound data transfer, but charges for outbound data transfer. I don't understand what that exactly means. Does this means that data you upload to amazon is free, but data you download is not?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You have it correct. Data "inbound" to Amazon (that is, packet data that is destined for the Amazon cloud servers; for example, uploads and client requests) are free. Data "outbound" from Amazon is billed (that is, downloads from the cloud and responses to client requests).

Anyway, here is a picture that may help you visualize this

[image: Technet image]

Comment: Thanks Elliot! very useful answer. Hope it helps a lot of other people too.

Comment: So basically what I understand from this is that it's similar to a "Data Plan" from a phone carrier but they only charge you for the downloaded data or responses to http requests, is that correct?

Comment: @OzzyTheGiant If we're using a phone analogy, I would say: they only charge you for texts you send, receiving texts is free.